# Querying Items with DynamoDBClient using an Global Secondary Index (GSI) with a partition key (deviceId) and a sort key (timestamp)

Tags: express, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

So I have a Lambda function acting as a Express.js server and an API. I am hitting all of the endpoint correctly and data is being returned the way I want. The sole problem I am left with is a function that is supposed to return a list of items in the following format:

```
[
 {
 "id": "d8aaa50e-5b4d-4a6f-84f5-e508e594f84d",
 "deviceId": "dkajshdaksdhj",
 "humidity": "45",
 "light": "35",
 "ph": "55",
 "temp": "65",
 "timestamp": 1696600485,
 "waterTemp": "75"
 },
 {...}
]
```

However when performing a QueryCommand on my table like so:

```
      const data = await dynamoDb.send(
        new QueryCommand({
          TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME_READINGS,
          IndexName: 'deviceId-timestamp-index', // Use the name of your Global Secondary Index
          KeyConditionExpression: '#deviceId = :deviceId AND #t BETWEEN #e AND #s',
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#deviceId': 'deviceId',
            '#t': 'timestamp',
            '#e': 'end',
            '#s': 'start',
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall(
            {
              ':deviceId': deviceId,
              ':s': start,
              ':e': end,
            },
            {
              removeUndefinedValues: true,
            },
          ),
          ScanIndexForward: false,
        }),
      );
```

I am getting hit with the following error:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "statusCode": "500",
    "stack": "Error: ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type\n    at Object.getHistoricalReadingsForDeviceId (file:///var/task/code/services/deviceService.js:240:11)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async getHistoricalReadings (file:///var/task/code/controllers/deviceController.js:75:32)"
}
```

Now I have checked both with ChatGPT, [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/dynamodb/command/QueryCommand/) and StackOverflow but after a day of trying out things I am now without options.

In the AWS Console the following Query works properly and it is returning items:
[image]

However when I try both on my deployed [website](https://stg-amplifychanges-4-10-23.d2w95gfx7rgwd6.amplifyapp.com/) and in Postman the result is the same (this error):

[image]

Link to repository in Github and exact file and line of the function is located: [click](https://github.com/Automating-Hydroponics-BPR2/via-sem7-bpr2/blob/b224a33841ef8b467eb2c07c93990ec97d78ba84/amplify/backend/function/bpr2lambda1/src/code/services/deviceService.js#L187)

My speculation is that it is complaining either because I do not have start or end as attributes in my table or because I am trying to marshall multiple things at once? [Link to marshall/unmarshall docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/functions/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.marshall.html). It is basically an utility function that is helping with converting from/to DynamoDB attribute types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExpressionAttributeNames are used for attribute names, such as `deviceId` and `timestamp`.

ExpressionAttributeValues are used for values, such as `start` and `end`.

Your code has mixed these up. Below should work.

```
const data = await dynamoDb.send(
        new QueryCommand({
          TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME_READINGS,
          IndexName: 'deviceId-timestamp-index', // Use the name of your Global Secondary Index
          KeyConditionExpression: '#deviceId = :deviceId AND #t BETWEEN :s AND :e',
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#deviceId': 'deviceId',
            '#t': 'timestamp'
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall(
            {
              ':deviceId': deviceId,
              ':s': start,
              ':e': end,
            }
          ),
          ScanIndexForward: false,
        }),
      );
```

As it's clear you'd rather work with native JSON, I believe you would see greater benefit using the DocumentClient, you can read more about that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/)

No marshalling required, it also means your results won't need to be unmarshalled:

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, QueryCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

const data = await docClient.send(
        new QueryCommand({
          TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME_READINGS,
          IndexName: 'deviceId-timestamp-index', // Use the name of your Global Secondary Index
          KeyConditionExpression: '#deviceId = :deviceId AND #t BETWEEN :s AND :e',
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#deviceId': 'deviceId',
            '#t': 'timestamp'
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ':deviceId': deviceId,
              ':s': start,
              ':e': end,
            },
          ScanIndexForward: false,
        }),
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried this but in the end I am getting the absolutely same error. Seems like I might as well try the DynamoDBDocumentClient if I still cannot seem to make this Query work tomorrow

Comment: You were indeed correct for one thing, however, I was passing a wrong value (start and end were treated as strings). I was so sure they are numbers (I send them as number from frontend) but then I just ran a check on them and they were strings ( I guess every parameter from query is converted to string?). parseInt(start) and parseInt(end) fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR

When getting values from query parameters keep in mind they are always strings. I was so sure that I am passing numbers from my frontend, hence the reason why I was so stuck. In the end a simple parseInt function solved my issue with a combination of the provided answers as well.

Working code below:

```
      const data = await dynamoDb.send(
        new QueryCommand({
          TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME_READINGS,
          IndexName: 'deviceId-timestamp-index', // Use the name of your Global Secondary Index
          KeyConditionExpression: '#deviceId = :deviceId AND #t BETWEEN :s AND :e',
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#deviceId': 'deviceId',
            '#t': 'timestamp',
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall(
            {
              ':deviceId': deviceId,
              ':s': parseInt(start),
              ':e': parseInt(end),
            },
            {
              removeUndefinedValues: true,
            },
          ),
          ScanIndexForward: false,
        }),
      );
```